# Send MMS using Twilio in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, sms, twilio, mms

I want to send MMS using [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/).
I am request one twilio url which is work fine on SMS but not MMS and I want to know what should change so i am sending MMS using [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) in iOS.
Here is my code.

```
NSLog(@"Sending request.");

// Common constants
NSString *kTwilioSID =@"Twilio SID";
NSString *kTwilioSecret =@"Twilio Secret";
NSString *kFromNumber = @"From Phone Number";
NSString *kToNumber = @"To Phone number";
NSString *kMessage=@"Hello This is Pintu vasani";

// Build request
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%@@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/%@/SMS/Messages", kTwilioSID, kTwilioSecret, kTwilioSID];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Set up the body  MediaUrl
NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From=%@&To=%@&Body=%@", kFromNumber, kToNumber, kMessage];
NSData *data = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

// Handle the received data
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSString *receivedString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Request sent. %@", receivedString);
}
```

Comment: Please Give Proper solution with one example.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You seem to be using the old, [deprecated Sms resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms) which doesn't support MMS. You really want to be using the [Messages resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) which does work.

On a separate note, I would not recommend making API calls directly to Twilio from your iOS application (or any other client application). To do this you would need to embed your Twilio credentials within the application which is dangerous. I would recommend sending the SMS/MMS from a server side application as in [this example](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-send-an-sms-from-ios-in-swift.html).

Comment: My SMS Working fine.But i don't get MMS.Can you please give some example which is send MMS.
Thanks.

Comment: Your SMS works fine because the deprecated Sms endpoint that you are using only does SMS. You need to change your URL to use the Messages endpoint (that I linked above) and that will work for both SMS and MMS.

Comment: As you give me link. I got this url but i don't know where to find {MessageSid} in below url   "/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages/{MessageSid}"

Comment: It's much the same as you already have, you need to make a POST request to /2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages. Any URL with a MessageSid in the request is for an existing message that you have already sent or received.